# DataGenerator(Sequence) - How to check batch_x and batch_y.shape?

Tags: python, types, shapes, data-generation

I have created this `DataGenerator`:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

I would like to check now `shape` and `type` of `batch_x` and `batch_y`. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question you are asking in here. Do you want to create a method to output that information?

Comment: No, I would like to get the shape and type of one batch of my x_set and y_set data to check if my Generator does what I expect.

Comment: Which types can your `x_set` and `y_set` have? Are you ok using [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, numpy is okay. Normally their types should be numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two `print` lines into your `__getitem__` function, that way each time your generator will be called, you'll see your desired informations :

```
print('batch_x : shape = %s, type = %s' % (batch_x.shape, batch_x.dtype) ) # If np.array
print('batch_y : shape = %s, type = %s' % (batch_y.shape, batch_y.dtype) )
```